# Add comment_id on Comments page within wp-admin

Tags: comments

In the backend of WordPress, on the Comments page. Is possible to include a column for comment_id?  Here is a visual of the locaton...

[image]

...perhaps to the left of the Comment column? If so, what would be an efficient way of doing that?

**or** if easier, under the 127.0.0.1 for each comment?  Either way, I just need a visual because that number will be significant in what my non-technical client needs in another task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is possible to include a column for comment_id?

Yes, and there are two hooks that you'd want to use:

- [`manage_edit-comments_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_screen-id_columns/) — use this hook to add custom columns to the comments list table, e.g. the custom comment ID column.
- [`manage_comments_custom_column`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_comments_custom_column/) — use this hook to display (`echo`) the content for a custom column added via the above hook.

Working example you can try:

```php
// Add the comment ID column.
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', function ( $columns ) {
    $columns['comment_id'] = 'ID';
    return $columns;
} );

// Display the content of the above column.
add_action( 'manage_comments_custom_column', function ( $column_name, $comment_ID ) {
    if ( 'comment_id' === $column_name ) {
        echo $comment_ID;
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

Additionally, if I were you, I'd probably want to make the comment ID column be *sortable* (so that the comments list can be sorted by clicking on the "ID" column in the table header/footer), and for that, you can use the [`manage_edit-comments_sortable_columns` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-id_sortable_columns/) to add the column to the sortable columns list:

```php
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_sortable_columns', function ( $columns ) {
    $columns['comment_id'] = 'comment_id';
    return $columns;
} );
```

Note that the `comment_id` doesn't need extra coding to make the comments sorting works, so you could simply add the column to the sortable columns list — for other custom columns, you may need to write the code for sorting the comments based on the specific custom column.

Comment: had no idea it was so easy.  Thank you!